# Forward slash in a Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a Python regex to find a mathematical expression in a string. The problem is that the forward slash seems to do something unexpected. I'd have thought that `[\w\d\s+-/*]*` would work for finding math expressions, but it finds commas too for some reason. A bit of experimenting reveals that forward slashes are the culprit. For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[/]*', 'a', 'bcd')
'abacada'
```

Apparently forward slashes match between characters (even when it is in a character class, though only when the asterisk is present). Back slashes do not escape them. I've hunted for a while and not found any documentation on it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Look [here for documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-re) on Python's `re` module.

I think it is not the `/`, but rather the `-` in your first character class: `[+-/]` matches `+`, `/` and any ASCII value between, which happen to include the comma.

Maybe this hint from the docs help:

> If you want to include a ']' or a '-' inside a set, precede it with a backslash, or place it as the first character.

Comment: RTFM is not an acceptable answer. The other answers are correct.

Answer (score 9):

You are saying it to replace *zero* or more slashes with `'a'`. So it does replace each "no character" with `'a'`. :)

You probably meant `[/]+`, i.e. one or more slashes.

**EDIT:** Read [Ber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643772/forward-slash-in-a-python-regex/1643823#1643823) for a solution to the original problem. I didn't read the whole question carefully enough.

Answer (score 4):

r'[/]*' means "Match 0 or more forward-slashes".  There are exactly 0 forward-slashes between 'b' & 'c' and between 'c' & 'd'.  Hence, those matches are replaced with 'a'.

Answer (score 3):

The `*` matches its argument zero or more times, and thus matches the empty string. The empty string is (logically) between any two consecutive characters. Hence

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'x*', 'a', 'bcd')
'abacada'
```

As for the forward slash, it receives no special treatment:

```
>>> re.sub(r'/', 'a', 'b/c/d')
'bacad'
```

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) describes the syntax of regular expressions in Python. As you can see, the forward slash has no special function.

The reason that `[\w\d\s+-/*]*` also finds comma's, is because inside square brackets the dash `-` denotes a *range*. In this case you don't want all characters between `+` and `/`, but a the literal characters `+`, `-` and `/`. So write the dash as the *last* character: `[\w\d\s+/*-]*`. That should fix it.